# Unreachable Code when using setContentView()

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
   menu.add(0, AUSRECHNEN_ID, Menu.NONE,"Umrechnen");
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

I get an "unreachable code" warning right next to the `setContentView()` method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What did you expect to happen with this snippet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning before you get to `setContentView(R.layout.main);`.  Move your return after the `setContentView` if you want to use this method call.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
   menu.add(0, AUSRECHNEN_ID, Menu.NONE,"Umrechnen");
   // MOVED HERE SO IT CAN BE CALLED
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```